# Add custom middleware to Laravel Passport endpoints

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware, laravel-passport

I have a standard Laravel Passport setup on 5.4 - it all works fine and is generating tokens.

I protect my API routes using the auth:api middleware as well as a custom middleware that checks that specific headers in a request are present and valid before any requests are handled. This middleware works fine for the API routes group.

Is there a way to wrap the Passport routes generated by laravel '.../oauth/token' in this middleware as well?

Currently I have set up the routes in my AuthServiceProvider.php boot() method:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    // Passport/OAuth
    Passport::routes(function ($router) {
      $router->forAccessTokens();
      $router->forTransientTokens();
    });

    Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(7));

    Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));
}
```

The end goal is that the oauth endpoints will return an error if the headers are not present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only need to add middleware to one Passport route for example `/oauth/token`, you can do it this way:

1. Look up the route you need by typing `php artisan r:l`
2. Check the controller and method used for this route, in out example it is going to be `AccessTokenController@issueToken`
3. Create the controller that extends AccessTokenController, you can leave it empty

> ```
> namespace App\Http\Controllers;
>
> use Illuminate\Http\Request;
> use Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController;
>
> class ApiTokenController extends AccessTokenController
> {
>
> }
> ```

4. Then create a route to that controller and method (as this controller inherits all the parent controller methods):

`Route::middleware('MyMiddleware')->post('/api-token', 'ApiTokenController@issueToken');`

Answer (score 20):

You can try this:
Go to `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider` and look for the `function boot()`. In this function you will see a line for registering routes for Passport. The default code is `Passport::routes()`. This `routes()` method accepts an options array as second argument. You can use it to set middlewares for Passport routes.

```
Passport::routes(null, ['middleware' => 'api']);
```

Comment: This worked for me. To target a specific route within the middleware:


   ` public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if( $request->path() != 'oauth/authorize' || $request->method() != 'POST' ) {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }`

Answer (score 7):

In the `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider` include the Route facade by adding this use statement somewhere in the top:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

Then on the `boot()` method, put the Passport::routes() inside a Route::group() like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'MyFunkyCustomMiddleware'], function(){
    Passport::routes(); // <-- Replace this with your own version
});
```

Hope that helps!